# Angular rxjs concat 2 Observables and return a tuple of them both

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 api calls that need to take place one after the other in sync.
I'm using the rxjs `concat` operator in order to accomplish the sync.
This works great but how do i return the data from both observables?
This is how i implement it:

```
const userId='someId';
this.restangular.one('users/generate-api-token').customPOST() // Will return an api token
  .concatMap(({token}) => this.restangular.one(`users/${userId}/api-token-details`).get()) // Will return the token's detail
  .map((data) => {
    console.log(data) // I would like to get both token and details here
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use resultSelector function of concatMap

```
Rx.Observable.of('123')
  .concatMap(ev => Rx.Observable.of('abc'), (x,y) => [x,y])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const userId='someId';

this.restangular.one('users/generate-api-token').customPOST() // Will return an api token
  .switchMapTo(this.restangular.one(`users/${userId}/api-token-details`).get(), (apiToken, tokenDetails) => ({apiToken, tokenDetails})) // Will return the token's detail
  .do(({apiToken, tokenDetails}) => {
    console.log(apiToken, tokenDetails);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/map) operator with TypeScript [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and return a tuple with extra data from your `concatMap`

```
const a$ = of(1, 2, 3);
const b$ = of('a', 'b', 'c');

a$.pipe(
    concatMap(a => 
        b$.pipe(
            map(b => [a, b] as const)
        )
    ),
    map(([a, b]) => console.log(a, b)) // both can be used here
).subscribe();
```